# Omnet++ / INET : How to get RSSI from 802.11 NIC?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am implementing a wireless routing protocol in a node model, which uses a network interface card of type Ieee80211Nic and it is set to work in ad-hoc mode (Ieee80211MgmtAdhoc). I would like to use the RSSI value from the NIC as one of the metrics in the routing protocol. 
How can I retrieve the RSSI value for a specific neighbour node (identified by its MAC address) from the NIC ?

**Edit**:

After some digging in the INET 3.6 source code, I found that the Ieee80211NIC component is composed of the following modules (or layers) (in top-down order):

- agent (used only in infrastructure mode in a station STA)
- mgmt (can be of type Ieee80211MgmtAP, Ieee80211MgmtSTA, Ieee80211MgmtAdhoc)
- mac
- radio

I further analyzed the **Ieee80211MgmtSTA** source code, and found that it implements the following method, which records the received signal strength (**bss.setRxPower(ap->rxPower)**):

```
void Ieee80211MgmtSTA::sendScanConfirm()
{
    EV << "Scanning complete, found " << apList.size() << " APs, sending confirmation to agent\n";

    // copy apList contents into a ScanConfirm primitive and send it back
    int n = apList.size();
    Ieee80211Prim_ScanConfirm *confirm = new Ieee80211Prim_ScanConfirm();
    confirm->setBssListArraySize(n);
    auto it = apList.begin();
    //XXX filter for req'd bssid and ssid
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++, it++) {
        APInfo *ap = &(*it);
        Ieee80211Prim_BSSDescription& bss = confirm->getBssList(i);
        bss.setChannelNumber(ap->channel);
        bss.setBSSID(ap->address);
        bss.setSSID(ap->ssid.c_str());
        bss.setSupportedRates(ap->supportedRates);
        bss.setBeaconInterval(ap->beaconInterval);
        bss.setRxPower(ap->rxPower);
    }
    sendConfirm(confirm, PRC_SUCCESS);
}
```

However, in case of the **Ieee80211MgmtAdhoc** type, the channel scanning (which is controlled by the agent module) is not implemented. Hence, it is not possible to retrieve the Rx Power for a specific node.

Has anybody managed to implement an agent module with channel scanning in the Adhoc mode ? 
Or is there an alternative way to get the RSSI information ?

Comment: The implementation of the ad-hoc management module is quite limited actually. I am considering the following changes to enable the reading of RSSI: 1. add beacon broadcasting to the Ieee80211MgmtAdhoc class ; 2. add a table for holding RSSI levels for neighbouring nodes ; 3. modify the computeReceptionIndication() method in SNIRReceiverBase class (in radio module) to add the RSSI reading into the ReceptionIndication structure which is attached to a MAC frame. >> The idea is to read the RSSI from beacon frames and add it to the table of neighbour nodes

Answer (score 0):

So, have you done your work?
As we know, there exist a implemented method which records the received signal strength `bss.setRxPower(ap->rxPower)`.
But in the same file we could found that the variable of ap is initial at the function of `storeAPInfo(const MACAddress& address, const Ieee80211BeaconFrameBody& body)`.
See below:

```
void Ieee80211MgmtSTA::storeAPInfo(const MACAddress& address, const Ieee80211BeaconFrameBody& body)
{
    APInfo *ap = lookupAP(address);
    if (ap) {
        EV << "AP address=" << address << ", SSID=" << body.getSSID() << " already in our AP list, refreshing the info\n";
    }
    else {
        EV << "Inserting AP address=" << address << ", SSID=" << body.getSSID() << " into our AP list\n";
        apList.push_back(APInfo());
        ap = &apList.back();
    }

    ap->channel = body.getChannelNumber();
    ap->address = address;
    ap->ssid = body.getSSID();
    ap->supportedRates = body.getSupportedRates();
    ap->beaconInterval = body.getBeaconInterval();
    //XXX where to get this from?
    //ap->rxPower = 。。。
}
```

As we can see, the ap->rxPower has not initial which mean that the value we get in the function of `sendScanConfirm()` will be always zero. So, Is there any other way to get the RSSI ?

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the source code, I`ve found a interesting function

```
 bool computeIsReceptionPossible(const IListening *listening, const IReception *reception, IRadioSignal::SignalPart part) const
```

in the file FlatReceiverBase which path could be "#include"inet/physicallayer/base/packetlevel/FlatReceiverBase". See below:

```
bool FlatReceiverBase::computeIsReceptionPossible(const IListening *listening, const IReception *reception, IRadioSignal::SignalPart part) const
{
    if (!NarrowbandReceiverBase::computeIsReceptionPossible(listening, reception, part))
        return false;
    else {
        const FlatReceptionBase *flatReception = check_and_cast<const FlatReceptionBase *>(reception);
        W minReceptionPower = flatReception->computeMinPower(reception->getStartTime(part), reception->getEndTime(part));
        bool isReceptionPossible = minReceptionPower >= sensitivity;
        EV_DEBUG << "Computing whether reception is possible: minimum reception power = " << minReceptionPower << ", sensitivity = " << sensitivity << " -> reception is " << (isReceptionPossible ? "possible" : "impossible") << endl;
        return isReceptionPossible;
    }
}
```

So, we could find that in this function we could get the receive power with minReceptionPower variable. Then, we could use the in embedded math operator mW2dBm to convert receive power to RSSI value.
Note,if tracing the source , we could find that this module is initialized at Ieee80211Radio module.
I hope that could be some help with people who encountered same problem .